# Simplest spring-mvc testing setup fails to start

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, junit

I am using Java based config with Maven, I've minimized the setup in order to isolate the error, yet I have no idea what is causing it except for the fact that removing the @EnableWebMvc annotation (which I obviously need) allows test to start and pass.

ExampleTest.java

```
package co.farel.server.services.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import co.farel.server.services.test.config.WebConfig;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebConfig.class})
public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
package co.farel.server.services.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mikolaj.nalecz.testy</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-spring-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I try to run the test, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [co.farel.server.services.test.config.WebConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
```

The entire stacktrace http://pastebin.com/0DxXAS0P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably caused by the fact that the container will provide Java servlet classes at runtime, however during the tests I need a jar to provide them.

After adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

To pom.xml and:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

To my ExampleTest.java, everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have invalid `import` statements in your project.

Most likely the invalid `import` is as following:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

Try adding the following dependencies to you POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In full version of my testing environment I do have those imports, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please add annotation **@WebAppConfiguration** to your Test Class

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried it before and it does not affect the outcome.